# what part of mm_struct use by kernel thread in linux?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

Kernel thread does not have memory descriptor it use mm_struct of last used process

how and what part of mm_struct use by kernel thread?

is it clear all detail of previous process?

Comment: It uses kernel part of page tables, because they are equivalent for last process mm and current kthread

Answer (score 1):

kernel threads runs only in kernel address space. They don't have access to user space virtual memory and they only use kernel space memory address after `PAGE_OFFSET`. So `(struct task_struct *)->mm` field in the process descriptor is NULL. You would require to dynamically allocate memory within your kernel thread if required.